# Angular directive for customized html tag in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, ng-bind-html

I got a solution to use AngularJS directive to let html understand my tag **bold** as the html tag **b**. So `<bold>{{testWorks}}</bold>` will style the text as bold when I have textWorks in the scope.

However, it doesn't work when I have `{{testText}}` where in the scope it is: `$scope.testText = "<bold>Peter</bold>";`

It also doesn't work when I use `ng-bind-html` to let the value to be evluated as html, you can find the code from [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m69Ot7FuVMhO4FpnYBoT?p=preview)

Could it be that the directive was applied before the evaluation of the expression?

Comment: For something like this, you should probably use a class filter, rather than an element filter.  Then you can do `<div class="directiveClass">Text<div/>`

Answer (score 3):

In order to bind some html to an angular variable you have to use the $sce module to verify the content.

live sample: 
    http://plnkr.co/edit/NBFsepObvv5IujigTosK?p=preview

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.testText = $sce.trustAsHtml("<bold>Peter</bold>");

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to change you controller to the followning

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
      $scope.testWorks = 'John';
      $scope.testText = $sce.trustAsHtml("<bold>Peter</bold>");
      $scope.testTable = [$sce.trustAsHtml('<bold>A</bold>'), $sce.trustAsHtml('<bold>B</bold>'), $sce.trustAsHtml('<bold>C</bold>')];
    }]);
```

and you html to:

```
<tr>
    <td ng:repeat="data in testTable" ng-bind-html="data"> </td> 
</tr>
```

[here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0npI02BgyE4SF7Kzuicm?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for both *Polochon* and *rishal*, I got it work with `$sce.trustAsHtml($compile("<bold>A</bold>")($scope).html()`. You can find it from here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0npI02BgyE4SF7Kzuicm?p=preview)

Comment: hi, the compile create a 'jquery' node that give you access to the append and prepend functions. It's needed when you want add a directive to the DOM after the page loading. However if you use an angular variable you dont need to compile before adding. just use trustAsHtml.